# Getting wrong results on first row of a query

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm using mysql and I have a query that is almost working perfectly.
I have the following three tables:

**Article**

> - article_id

**Comment**

> - comment_id
> - article_id

**View**

> - view_id
> - article_id

And I want to put all this information together in one query. I want to see how many views and comments each article has.
I've managed to make one with the help of some great people today but I'm stuck again.

```
SELECT article.id_article,
       COUNT(view.id_article),
       COUNT(comment.id_article) 
FROM article LEFT JOIN view ON article.id_article = view.id_article 
             LEFT JOIN comment ON article.id_article = comment.id_article 
GROUP BY id_article 
ORDER BY id_article
```

What happens is that, only the first row shows wrong results. Instead of 4 comments and 3 views, I see 24 on both and don't know why, because all the rest is fine. Seems like the number of comments is being quadruplicate and reproduced in the first row on both comments and views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a cartesian product with your join:

1 Article * 4 views * 3 comments = 12

Not sure why you are getting 24, probably you have 2 articles with the same ID for the first row.

```
SELECT article.id_article,
       COUNT(distinct view.id_view),
       COUNT(distinct comment.id_comment) 
FROM article LEFT JOIN view ON article.id_article = view.id_article 
             LEFT JOIN comment ON article.id_article = comment.id_article 
GROUP BY id_article 
ORDER BY id_article
```

another way to write this query can be:

```
   SELECT article.id_article,
          v.n_views,
          c.n_comments
     FROM article 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT article_id,
                  count(*) n_views
             FROM view 
         GROUP BY article_id) v ON article.id_article = v.id_article 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT article_id,
                  count(*) n_comments
             FROM comment 
         GROUP BY article_id) c ON article.id_article = c.id_article 
    GROUP BY id_article 
    ORDER BY id_article
```

Comment: Same as above's response: I can't use DISTINCT or else I will only get 1 for all results... and I want all of them ;)

Comment: try the other version :)

Comment: It's working perfecly! Thanks! That's a nice long query hehehe

Comment: Anyway the distinct is not on article_id

Comment: Weird... now that I've tried the first again for curiosity, it worked! Well, I'm going to use the first one since it is simpler and easier to understand for me :) Thanks again!

Comment: If you count distinct the article_id you will get one because each article has a unique id, if you count view or comment ids you will get the correct results